# How can I add an image taking half the container width with parallax?

Tags: html, css, image, parallax

I want the section of the website to look like this:
[image]

But right now mine looks like this:

[image]

How can I increase the height of the image on the right to cover the full height of the `about-sec` container?

Here is my CSS code:

```
.about-sec {
  width: 100%;
  /* display: flex; */
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 2% 0.5% 10% 0.5%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.left-half {
    width: 50%;
    position: abosulte;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    /*  */

}

.right-half {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url("aboutSectionImage.jpg");
    background-color: #cccccc;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    width: 50%;
    right: 0px;
    height: 6em;
    display: flex;

    /* padding-left: 10%;
    padding-top: 10%; */
}
```

Here is my React/HTML code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './aboutSection.css';


class AboutSection extends React.Component {

    render() { 
        return (
            <div className="about-sec" >
               <div className="left-half">
                    asd
               </div>
               <div className="right-half">
                   Hi
                   <br></br>
                   df
               </div>
               
            </div>
        );
    }
}
 
export default AboutSection;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
padding: 2% 0.5% 0 0.5%;
```

use this in about-sec

Comment: Do you know how to make the image on the right the same height as the container about-sec?